# Extracting regions from image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

Hi I am trying to retrieve regions from a set of images. I have used bitwise_and operation on the image and masks to get the regions but doing so is resulting in change of brightness in the resulting image. So, I want to retrieve these regions from the image pixel by pixel and put them together in another blank image.

**Update:** Currently, I have three regions in the masks (white, grey, and black). I want to be able to select a region(say white or grey) and then for that particular region it should extract the image for the corresponding region.

```
for im in glob.glob(path_to_images):
        image = cv2.imread(im)  

        canny = auto_canny(image)


        image[(image< 50)] = 0
        gray_mask = image[(image>= 50) & (image< 100)] = 100
        white_mask = image[image> 110] = 255



        if(white_mask):
            res = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = white_mask )
            white_inv= cv2.bitwise_not(white_mask)
            alt_ = cv2.bitwise_and(img_1, img_1, mask = white_inv)
            result = cv2.add(alt_, res)

        elif(gray_mask):
            res = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = gray_mask )
            gray_inv= cv2.bitwise_not(gray_mask)
            alt_ = cv2.bitwise_and(img_1, img_1, mask = gray_inv)
            result = cv2.add(alt_, res)





        cv2.imshow("result",result)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I have tried this but the extracted regions results in increased brightness.

**Update 2:** I tried the solution given by @ZdaR but I got the following error: "error: (-215) (mtype == 0 || mtype == 1) && _mask.sameSize(*psrc1) in function cv::binary_op"

[Link to sample images](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XV18vPXEw9vuWihgk-kx8h8gvMdnQGAl)

[Expected output](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rTwisBjRTMHwroyI5t-bb-KApINamYYb)

[My output](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CdXsaDu08FW2bGdLJL18FogkynlXBT64)

[Masks](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qecYT5INs0OnpGETpLizzNDScalYVH6_)

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example to your specific problem and your images. You should be able to use numpy slicing to extract those regions and even put them into a new blank image.

Comment: @fmw42 added the sample images with current output and expected output

Comment: @fmw42 so what I understood right now is that for the grey regions of the mask the brightness is increased but for white regions it is still extracting regions correctly.

Comment: "Expected Output" shows 404 Error. So I am not sure what you want. Why are you trying to use the gray parts? Why not just threshold to white. Then bitwise_and should work the way you expect. What do you expect from masking with the gray parts? Perhaps what you want is to make your masks floats in the range 0 to 1 and then just multiply the masks with the images. That will reduce the brightness for gray area in the mask. The 1s will mask to no change and the 0s will mask to black.

Comment: Please provide full code so others can test it with your images. Please read this forum's help section about providing a minimal, complete, and verifiable example to your specific problem

Comment: @fmw42 I am trying to divide the image into regions(right now white, grey and black) and then I want to pick those regions from original images. It can be both white and grey or just white or just grey depending on the requirement. So, the approach to convert the grey region to white can not be possible.

Comment: @fmw42 based on a particular region from the mask I want to grab the region so that is why I wanted to know how to pick region pixel by pixel and not by using bitwise_and

Comment: @fmw42 I have corrected the "expected output" folder. Let me know if it is still not accessible

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand how you got the expected results. Do you have a link/reference to some other code or technique? I am not able to spend more time on this tonight. I am not sure I understand what to expect from bitwise_and using gray values and not just white and black.

Comment: @fmw42 I have applied two level thresholding on the images and generated the gray and white mask regions. Then I performed the bitwise_and on these masks. The only problem I am facing is that the gray mask regions are producing images with increased intensity. Is there a way to make it look like the image region from white masks. Suppose I only want to select the gray mask and extract image for it it should appear like the original image region not the highlighted region as in the expected output. I hope it clears some doubts

Comment: Please always show your code. See ZdaR's answer. That is what I was suggesting you do. You can even adjust the brightness of each resulting image if you want and/or combine them into one image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step would be separate out the gray and white masks independently using either `cv2.threshold` or `cv2.inRange()` methods, then we can simply use `cv2.min()` method to take the imprint of the original image at the gray and white areas respectively as:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def extract_gray_mask(input_image, composite_mask):
    gray_mask = cv2.inRange(composite_mask, np.array([100]), np.array([120]))
    gray_mask = cv2.cvtColor(gray_mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

    return cv2.min(input_image, gray_mask)


def extract_white_mask(input_image, composite_mask):
    white_mask = cv2.inRange(composite_mask, np.array([250]), np.array([255]))
    white_mask = cv2.cvtColor(white_mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

    return cv2.min(input_image, white_mask)


input_image = cv2.imread("/path/to/original_img.png")
composite_mask = cv2.imread("/path/to/mask.png", 0)

img_1 = extract_gray_mask(input_image, composite_mask)
img_2 = extract_white_mask(input_image, composite_mask)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time out to do this. It looks really amazing. I just have few questions. I have not saved my masks as an image. They are just numpy arrays so how to access them here using this code? And is it a good practice to store the masks as images? And if yes, then how to ensure that the input image and corresponding masks is accessible at the same time meaning image1 and mask1, image 2 and mask2?

Comment: You can just omit this line: `composite_mask = cv2.imread("/path/to/mask.png", 0)` and simply initialize the `composite_mask` with the numpy array itself. Just make sure it is a single channel image and not a 3-channel image.